# Find the mistake on the "proof" that $\exists x(\neg p(x)\land\neg q(x))\implies\exists x\,\neg p(x)\land\exists x\,\neg q(x)$

Tags: first-order-logic, quantifiers, fake-proofs

> Find the mistake on the "proof" that $$\exists x(\neg p(x)\land\neg q(x))\implies\exists x\,\neg p(x)\land\exists x\,\neg q(x).$$

---

"Proof":

$$
\begin{array}{lll}
1)&\exists x(\neg p(x)\land\neg q(x))&\text{Premise}\\
2)&\neg p(a)\wedge\neg q(a)&\text{Existential particularization 1)}\\
3)&\neg p(a)&\text{Conjunction elimination 2)}\\
4)&\neg q(a)&\text{Conjunction elimination 2)}\\
5)&\exists x\,\neg p(x)&\text{Existential generalization 3)}\\
6)&\exists x\,\neg q(x)&\text{Existential generalization 4)}\\
7)&\exists x\,\neg p(x)\land\exists x\,\neg q(x)&\text{Conjunction introduction 5,6)}\\
\end{array}
$$

**This is not a valid proof because of line $6)$: we must not suppose that when doing the generalization, we call this $x$ but another element, namely $y$, with the possibility that $x\neq y$.**

So line $6)$ should be $\exists y\,\neg q(y)$, and then we cannot apply line $7)$. Thus this is not a valid proof.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Is there a typo somewhere? Why does it say "$\exists x \wedge \neg q(x)$"? Is there an extra $\wedge$?

Comment: @WillieWong it was a typo, thanks :) What do you think now?

Comment: Furthermore, I think $\exists x (\neg p(x) \wedge \neg q(x) )\implies \exists x \neg p(x) \wedge \exists x \neg q(x)$ is in fact true. What's false is the reverse implication.

Comment: @WillieWong but you did see the proof I shown. Do you agree with it? I think the error is on line $6)$, I explain why on the question.

Comment: I think the proof you showed is ok. (Don't see any mistakes there.) There's no difference between $\exists x \neg p(x) \wedge \exists x \neg q(x)$ and $\exists x \neg p(x) \wedge \exists y \neg q(y)$.

Comment: The proof is sound and $\exists x Px$ and $\exists y Py$ have the same "meaning".

Comment: You know that there is a Black Dog (this means $\exists x Bx \land Dx$); from it it follows that there is a Dog and there is a Black (thing), i.e. $\exists x Bx \land \exists y Dx$.

Comment: It is true and your proof is correct. Line 6 is correct, since $x$ is not a free variable in $(\exists x)(\neg P(x) \land \neg Q(x))$. If you are using some other variable $y$ which is free in $P(a)$ or $Q(a)$, then you are in trouble.

Comment: I am with the other commenters: there is no mistake in this proof at all.

Comment: It is *existential particularisations* that must assume distinct witnesses, since two existential statements, even when having the same bound variable, *might* not have a common witness.  However two statements about a common witness *can* be *generalised* to two existential statements with the same bound variable (or a different bound variable, if you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **This is not a valid proof because of line $6)$: we must not suppose that when doing the generalization, we call this $x$ but another element, namely $y$, with the possibility that $x\neq y$.**
>
> So line $6)$ should be $\exists y\,\neg q(y)$, and then we cannot apply line $7)$. Thus this is not a valid proof.
>
> Is my reasoning correct?

No. Not correct. Just because you use the same variable twice does not mean that they have to refer to the same object. A statement like $\exists x \ Even(x) \land \exists x \ Odd(x))$ is true for the natural numbers, as indeed "there is at least one even number and there exists at least one odd number", but clearly under this interpretation the $x$'s have to refer to different objects.